# Simple hash function techniques

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm pretty new to hashing in Java and I've been getting stuck on a few parts. I have a list of 400 items (and stored in a list of 1.5x = 600), which the item id's range from 1-10k. I've been looking at a few hash functions and I initially copied the examples in the packet, which just used folding. I noticed that I've been getting about 50-60% null nodes, which is apparently too many. I also noticed that just modding the id by 600 tends to reduce it to a solid 50% nulls.

My current hash function looks something like, and for being as ugly as it is, it's *only* a 1% decrease in nulls from a simple modding, with an avg list length of 1.32...

```
   public int getHash( int id )
   {
      int hash = id;

      hash <<= id % 3;
      hash += id << hash % 5;

      /* let's go digit by digit! */          
      int digit;
      for( digit = id % 10;
           id != 0;
           digit = id % 10, id /= 10 )
      {
         if ( digit == 0 ) /* prevent division by zero */
            continue;
         hash += digit * 2;
      }

      hash >>= 5;
      return (hash % 600);
   }
```

What are some good techniques for creating **simple** hash functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would keep it simple. Return the `id` of your element as your hashcode, and let the hashtable worry about rehashing it if it feels it needs to. **Your goal should be to make a hash code unique to your object**.

The Java HashMap uses the following rehashing method:

```
/**
 * Applies a supplemental hash function to a given hashCode, which
 * defends against poor quality hash functions.  This is critical
 * because HashMap uses power-of-two length hash tables, that
 * otherwise encounter collisions for hashCodes that do not differ
 * in lower bits. Note: Null keys always map to hash 0, thus index 0.
 */
static int hash(int h) {
    // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
    // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
    // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
    h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
    return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice review article [here](http://www.concentric.net/~ttwang/tech/inthash.htm). Also, the [Wikipedia article on hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) is a good overview. It suggests using a chi-squared test to assess the quality of your hash function.